# Taking logarithm of sum and products

Tags: logarithms

$\newcommand{\cost}{\operatorname{cost}}$My cost-metric is in following form

\begin{equation}
\cost(x,y) = A(x,y_1) \times \sum_{i}b_i B_i(x,y_i)\tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $A$ and $B$'s follow normal distribution. For my computer implementation, I am thinking of taking $\log(\cdot)$ to avoid computing exponential. By taking log of (1), I get

\begin{equation}
\log(\cost(x,y)) = \log(A(x,y_1)) + \log\left(\sum_i b_i B_i(x,y_i)\right)
\end{equation}

which simplifies first term but second term remains unchanged. Can I bring $\log(\cdot)$ inside the summation?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B_i$ all independent of each other? In what what do they depend on $x$ and $y$? Are those supposed to be parameters identifying which normal distribution it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't bring the logarithm inside the summation because that's equivalent to saying that the logarithm of a sum is the sum of logarithms.